# Upgrade of HTC software hid Nexus 7 from adb

Tags: adb, nexus-7, stock-android, windows, htc-one

`adb devices` shows my device in its listing up until I installed a new version of the HTC Sync Manager (for my HTC One M7).

I've also tried reinstalling the device drivers and even adding a new `%CompositeAdbInterface%` with my Hardware ID in: `<android sdk>\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`.

Note that: I'm running stock Android 5.1.1 on Windows 8.1 x64.

#### How do I get my Nexuz 7 to register with `adb` again?

Answer (score 0):

I definitely suggest using [Koush's Universal ADB Driver](https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver), rather than a device specific driver set to use ADB. It covers all possible ADB interfaces and generally works well with multiple devices from different manufacturers.

Comment: I think I tried that before installing the official one, and it didn't detect my Nexus

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly most HIDs are usually transmitted from inside a device by it's firmware and often are embedded into hardware.

Long story on the bottom, but basically try what I did: install previous version of Sync Manager, test if drivers work and backup the working ones if possible (Kies keeps them in installation directory, not sure about HTC sync manager), so you can use them without the old sync manager.

Also 1 thing to note: Keep your sync software off when connecting your device, because it WILL attempt to use the normal usb drivers.

---

I went through hours of similar stuff with Galaxy S4. Drivers "worked" but were not really usable. Only conclusion I came to is adb drivers were overridden by default usb ones.
None of "unversal" nor device specific adb drivers installed anything that worked with my phone/PC setup. I ended up going through different versions of Kies (Samsung alternative to Sync Manager) since evidently it contains and overrides adb drivers. Eventually, i found a version of Kies that had compatible adb drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If you had installed multiple USB drivers or connected different USB devices then this happens. The first step will be to get rid of all USB drivers from your system and then install the one supplied via the Android SDk. After the installation, connect your nexus 7 for it be discovered.  I could get my samsung phone recognized only after doing this. I hope it works for you as well. Good luck.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Will give it a go on the weekend.